# How could a field in another table in a datatable of angular by means of a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, django, angular, typescript

I have data table in angular and one of the fields or column of that table is a foreign key, I mean an ID (computer_id), but I want to show in place of that ID a field of another table, that is, I have in the table records (table that I am showing) a team id as a foreign key and I want to show the name of that team, which is a column of the table of equipment (table of which I have its id as a foreign key in the table of records).

I have no idea how to do it in angular, if you gave me an idea they would help me a lot.

PD: to bring me the data from the database, I am consuming the api through http queries and using django rest framework, my doubt would be if I have to bring me by query http get the two tables but then as I do relation for the table records.

As a database manager I am using MYSQL

Below I leave the files of how I link the data to my data table

service.ts

```
  public getAllEquipos() : Observable<Equipos[]> {
          return this.http.get<Equipos[]>(this.baseurl + 'equipos')
          } 

  public getAllPort() : Observable<Port[]> {
          return this.http.get<Port[]>(this.baseurl + 'puertos')
          }
```

home.component.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  nuevosEquipos: any[]=[];
    constructor(
      // Inject services
      private http: HttpRequestsService,
      private service:PrtgService,
      private dialog: MatDialog,

    ) { }

    displayedColumns: string[] = ['id_equipo', 'nombre', 'vendedor','ip_gestion','tipo','localidad','categoria','name_port','ultima_actualizacion','actions',];  
    dataSource:any;  

@ViewChild(). 
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    //@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;                    

    ngOnInit() {                        

      this.service.getAllEquipos().subscribe(Data => { // Imprimiendo en consola para probar que esta leyendo el modelo en JSON
        console.log(Data);
      })

    this.RenderDataTable()  

    }

    RenderDataTable() {   

      this.service.getAllEquipos().subscribe(  
        (res) => {  
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();  
          this.dataSource.data = res;  
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
           console.log(res)

        },  
        (error) => {  
          console.log('Se produjo un error mientras intentaba recuperar 
                      Usuarios!' + error);  
        });

    }
```

equipo.ts (Interface)

```
export interface Equipos { 

    id_equipo: number;
    nombre: string;
    vendedor: string;
    ip_gestion:string;
    tipo: string;
    localidad:string;
    categoria:string;
    id_port: number;     // Here I have the id of my model (table) 
                         // "port"(id_port) and I want to show the 
                         // name of the port instead of the ID
    ultima_actualizacion:string;
}
```

port.ts (Interface)

```
export interface Port { 

    id_port: number;
    name_port: string;
    }
```

home.component.html

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="DoFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrar">
  </mat-form-field>

  <fa-icon id='new_equi' [icon]=icon_new class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onCreate()" matTooltip="Crear" matTooltipPosition="above"></fa-icon>
  <br>     
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" align="center">

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id_equipo">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID Equipo</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id_equipo}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre Equipo</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >{{element.nombre}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="vendedor">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vendedor</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.vendedor}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="ip_gestion">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>IP Gestion</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ip_gestion}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="tipo">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Tipo</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.tipo}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="localidad">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Localidad</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.localidad}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="categoria">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Categoria</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.categoria}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="id_port_port">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre Port</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id_port}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="ultima_actualizacion">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Ultima Actualizacion </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ultima_actualizacion | date:'d/M/yyyy, h:mm a'}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Acciones</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
           <fa-icon [icon]=icon_edit class="btn btn-success" (click)=onEdit(element) matTooltip="Editar" matTooltipPosition="left"></fa-icon>&nbsp;
           <fa-icon [icon]=icon_delete class="btn btn-danger" matTooltip="Eliminar" matTooltipPosition="right" ></fa-icon>
          </td>
        </ng-container>

  </table>        
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20,50,100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>          
</div>
```

How should I show the name_port in the id_port attribute using this foreign key?

Comment: You should prepare your data before giving it to table component, if you already have data in front end but as different objects, use those objects to prepare a new one which can be given to data table else fetch the details first then give it to Datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in both backend and frontend(angular app) you need to have a two separate model for creating (post) and get data, for example, we have a person model like below:

```
interface PersonForCreation {
    id:number;
    name: string;
    computerId: number;
}
```

this model is for creation and update and we need another model for get request like this:

```
interface Person {
    id:number;
    name: string;
    computer: Computer
}

interface Computer{
    id:number;
    name: string;
}
```

or you can prepare Person model for get like this in backend and send to client

```
interface Person {
    id:number;
    name: string;
    computerName: string;
}
```

and show computerName field in data table or p.Computer.name.

if you get ports and equipment separately without joining them in backend you can do this way in angular:

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id_port_port">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre Port</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{getPortName(element.id_port)}}</td>
    </ng-container>

  public getPortName(portId) {
      //when you request ports with getAllport save ports in array 
      //dictionary or find them in normal array 
      //theme later 
      //or return ports.find((port)=>(port.id === portId)).name
      return ports[portId];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did not understand the last code, how do I call the name of the computer in my person table in a data table?

Comment: how do you bind data to your data table?

Comment: I just placed the code linking my data to the data table after the request http get, in this case I want to show the name_port of the model port in the column where this id_port, I hope your answers, thanks

Comment: why you dont join port and equipos in backend to add port_name in the result and fetch that data to your data table ?

Comment: with your way  you should make multiple request to server for your datatable , i dont think this is good way, whats happen if you have many foreign key column?

Comment: You try to tell me that I must do the link through foreign key in the computer table from the backend? that is, in Django?

Comment: Is there no practical possibility to do so by angular? In total it would be 4 columns with a foreign key, and the option to edit those values, that is, the foreign key, will be available.

Comment: yes it's better to do that in django , but if you insist to solve the proplem in angular just get ports and store them in array then from mat table ui call a method that map id to name of the port {{element.id_port}} => {{getPortName(element.id_port)}}

Comment: Could you put a small example of how are you describing the last response? If it's not too much trouble and thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end I will do it in django rest framework from the backend, but your idea in angular will take it into account for future projects.